# Stop Office file type associations

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, windows-registry, file-association

Microsoft Office wants to use Microsoft Word as the default HTML editor. I do not want this. I changed the value at

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\Edit\command
```

However the next time I start Microsoft Word, it is set back to the "bad" value.

Comment: Do you mean all HTML files are opening in Microsoft Word instead of in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran
[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)
and discovered a registry value being queried

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Internet\DoNotCheckIfOfficeIsHTMLEditor
```

If you change the value it will stop this annoying feature

```
sp hkcu:software/microsoft/office/14.0/common/internet `
  DoNotCheckIfOfficeIsHTMLEditor 1 -t dword
```